# extending abstract model in Django

Tags: django, django-2.0, django-oauth

I'm using `Django 2.x` and `OAuth Toolkit`.

I'm writing an application where I need to add `ForeignKey` pointing to `Application` model of `OAuth Toolkit` plugin, which is defined **Abstract**.

According to [the documentation](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_topics.html#extending-the-application-model). I can extend the **AbstractApplication** and then add in settings

```
OAUTH2_PROVIDER_APPLICATION_MODEL='your_app_name.MyApplication'
```

In my case, I have created my app and in **models.py**

```
class CustomOAuthToolkitApplication(AbstractApplication):
    pass


class OAuthToolkitTrackingLog(models.Model):

    application_model = settings.OAUTH2_PROVIDER_APPLICATION_MODEL

    application = models.ForeignKey(application_model, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, default=None, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    col_1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and in **settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'oauth2_provider',
    'my_app',
]

OAUTH2_PROVIDER_APPLICATION_MODEL = 'my_app.CustomOAuthToolkitApplication'
```

But when I run command to generate migration

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

It gives error as

```
The field oauth2_provider.Grant.application was declared with a lazy reference to 'my_app.customoauthtoolkitapplication', but app 'my_app' isn't installed.
The field oauth2_provider.RefreshToken.application was declared with a lazy reference to 'my_app.customoauthtoolkitapplication', but app 'my_app' isn't installed.
```

**How can I fix this issue?**

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. I'm not sure. But as far as I remember from django source code, the order in INSTALLED_APPS matters. Could you please try switching places, so:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  ...
  'my_app',
  'oauth2_provider',
]
```

So that my_app is higher on the list?